# How to hide first pseudo css element

Tags: css

Is it possible to hide the first pseudo element?

```
<div id="builder-widgets_rule_0" class="ruleTemplate rule-container"> 
   <div class="custom-condition">AND</div>
</div>
<div id="builder-widgets_rule_1" class="ruleTemplate rule-container"> 
   <div class="custom-condition">AND</div>
</div>
<div id="builder-widgets_rule_2" class="ruleTemplate rule-container"> 
   <div class="custom-condition">AND</div>
</div>
```

this html element has a pseudo styling like this:

```
.custom-condition::before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   width: 1px;
   height: auto;
   min-height: 25px;
   border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
   top: -25px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -2px;
}
```

It is not possible to do something like this?

```
.custom-condition:first-child::before {
   content: '';
}
```

Also tried to added a span element to avoid the psuedo element like this:

```
<div id="builder-widgets_rule_0" class="ruleTemplate rule-container"> 
   <div class="custom-condition">AND</div>
   <div class="smallLine"></div>
</div>
<div id="builder-widgets_rule_1" class="ruleTemplate rule-container"> 
   <div class="custom-condition">AND</div>
   <div class="smallLine"></div>
</div>
<div id="builder-widgets_rule_2" class="ruleTemplate rule-container"> 
   <div class="custom-condition">AND</div>
   <div class="smallLine"></div>
</div>
```

Just copied the psuedo styling to the `.smallLine`

Comment: @MohammedAhmed That will depend on the HTML - which we do not have. Yes it is possible but only in specific circumstances.

Comment: You can set the `content` value to `none`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#Values.  That will reset it to not show the pseudo-element for the `first-child`.  Not sure if that's what you're asking for though.

Comment: Added the specific html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the elements are inside the same wrapper you can do this. Instead of removing the pseudo-element from the first simply define it for all the other but not the first.

```css
.custom-condition ~ .custom-condition::before {
  content: '[Before]';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div> OR </div>
  <div class="custom-condition"> AND </div>
  <div class="custom-condition"> AND </div>
  <div> OR </div>
  <div class="custom-condition"> AND </div>
</div>
```

**UDPATE**

You can consider the parent element with your current HTML structure

```css
.rule-container ~ .rule-container .custom-condition::before {
  content: '[Before]';
}
```

```html
<div id="builder-widgets_rule_0" class="ruleTemplate rule-container"> 
   <div class="custom-condition">AND</div>
</div>
<div id="builder-widgets_rule_1" class="ruleTemplate rule-container"> 
   <div class="custom-condition">AND</div>
</div>
<div id="builder-widgets_rule_2" class="ruleTemplate rule-container"> 
   <div class="custom-condition">AND</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that helped what is the css selector `~` meaning?

Comment: @Sireini it means select all the elements that come after https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors